# How to call a thread to run on specific time in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, timertask

I want o make threads execute at specific exact times (for example at: 2012-07-11 13:12:24 and 2012-07-11 15:23:45)

I checked `ScheduledExecutorService`, but it only supports executing after specific period from the first run and I don't have any fixed periods, instead I have times from database to execute tasks on.

In a previous question for a different problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361332/how-to-call-a-method-on-specific-time-in-java), TimerTask was the solution, but obviuosly I can't make thread a `TimerTask` as `Runnable` and `TimerTask` both have the method `run` which needs to be implemented. The question here if I make the thread extends `TimerTask` and have one implementation of `run()`, would that work? 
If not, then how it's possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Refactor your solution so you don't create your own thread. Extend a `TimerTask` instead.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that would solve the conflict.. but in fact i need the threads because i will have many tasks (there are four types of tasks) and i want each single task to be executed separately in a thread.

Comment: Then make a thin `TimerTask` wrapper that contains your `Thread` as an instance var and will `start` your thread at the scheduled time. You could even use an anonymous `TimerTask` subclass that sees the `Thread` by closing over a local var. And now I see that's exactly what @AkhilDev is proposing below :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use TimerTask .

Create a TimerTask object with a field variable as your thread.
Call the Thread start from the Timer task Run method.

```
public class SampleTask extends TimerTask {
  Thread myThreadObj;
  SampleTask (Thread t){
   this.myThreadObj=t;
  }
  public void run() {
   myThreadObj.start();
  }
}
```

Configure it like this.

```
Timer timer  new Timer();
Thread myThread= // Your thread
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.set(
  Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,
  Calendar.SUNDAY
);
date.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
// Schedule to run every Sunday in midnight
timer.schedule(
  new SampleTask (myThread),
  date.getTime(),
  1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
);
```

Comment: I'm try to implement this, but what would happen if I schedule the same task at the same time twice? for example, i checked now for due tasks and found t1. after one minute t1 was still due.. so it got scheduled with it's time..Is it going to be executed twice?

Comment: that scenario might actually be a result of the way I am fetching tasks from database.. I have a thread which runs every minute using executerService, that thread looks for any tasks that will be due in the next one minute and fetch them. If the task is due only one second after the that check, it would be considered for the next execution of the fetcher thread.. but as it will be due in one second after fetching thread time, it might be executed or even scheduled late..how can this be improved?

Comment: create 2 instances of the task, configured with different time and schedule both the instances.

Comment: but this will execute the task twice .. and the task stores results in DB. so executing twice would create a problem.. I am actually trying to avoid two executions of the same task.

Comment: @Sam you are asking an entirely different question now. Anyway, you have to put some flag column in DB to check its its executed or not some thing like tat. but i can't say if tat will be enough unless u post some code and point out the timing problem.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion , It's another question resulted from the first one.. anyways, i guess I am complicating it, the timing problem likelihood to happen is very low and probably would not affect so I would not consider for now.. I tried your solution and it worked for me. Thanks :)

Comment: if Calendar.Sunday is for only giving it on that day. What about EVERYDAY? is there any workaround using that Calendar Object (variables) ? @Sam

Comment: @gumuruh if you remove the 7 from the last line of code, i.e. making it: `timer.schedule(
  new SampleTask (myThread),
  date.getTime(),
  1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 
);`  that will repeat the task everyday at midnight starting from Sunday. Obviously, you can change Sunday to any other time you like.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should better use some library like the [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/). This is basically an implementation of cron for Java.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) from the java.util.concurrent package? It provides a count down then triggers the thread(s) to run. I never needed to use it myself, but have seen it in use a couple times.

Comment: It would be way simpler to just call `Thread.start` at the requested time.

Comment: what if he has more than one `Thread` that he needs to kickstart simultaneously?

Comment: A `for` loop might help there. (BTW not downvoting you).

Comment: Plus there is absolutely nothing wrong with looking at the alternatives available in that package. There are lots of useful stuff.

Comment: posdef, you propose an entirely viable solution. It is just my opinion that it could be overkill. Each new thread would have to know about the CDL and each `run` method would have to start with a boilerplate `cdl.await`. So you'd probably need a template method for that. And so on.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: well no worries, I guess... apparently someone did downvote the answer tho and it would be nice if that person was kind enough explain why :)

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree. In fact, in my book the only fair behavior towards fellow SOers is to 1. leave a comment; 2. give answerer at least 5 minutes to respond; 3. downvote if all else fails.

Comment: Recently I used `CountDownLatch` in an implementation of a distributed algorithm. In such algorithm, a client broadcasts a message to all the servers, and need only to wait for acks from half of them (no matter which serves). `CountDownLatch` was exactly the solution.

Comment: @hengxin glad it was useful :)

Comment: The CountDownLatch is a perfect solution, especially when trying to do testing on outside API's that claim to be thread safe.  Spawn threads in for loops, have them wait for the startSignal and then all hit the API.  Use the doneSignal to know when it is safe for your test code to verify that the API made the changes.