# Periodic actions in an Android application

Tags: java, android, timer, schedule, periodic-task

I'm looking for some solution to my current problem. I want to execute periodic action like this:
1. Start on 8.00AM
2. Change at 8:45 AM
3. Change at 8:55 AM
4. Change at 9:35 AM etc.

Of course we have to remember, that user can start application at, e.g. 8:33AM.
My code looks this:

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Log.v("Timer: ", String.valueOf(true));
                        actual.setText("Actual: " + mainScreenNotification.actualy());

                    }
                });

            }
        }, get8Morning());
```

---

```
private static Date get8Morning(){
        Date date = new Date();
        date.setHours(8);
        date.setMinutes(0);
        date.setSeconds(0);
        return date;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use `AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to set up event triggers like this. Your solution will only work while your application is in the foreground, and it is unlikely that the user will keep your application in the foreground permanently.

Comment: Concur, - use the system supplied functionality for this instead of trying to create all this yourself.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm looking for some informations about Threads (I don't need to run those operations while device is sleeping so I decided to use Threads as they said on site you've linked). I've found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432498/how-to-call-a-thread-to-run-on-specific-time-in-java . Again timer... what should I do then?

Comment: @tuksiarz: "I don't need to run those operations while device is sleeping" -- as I mention in my answer, your solution will only work while your application is in the foreground. Sleeping has nothing to do with it. Once your app is no longer in the foreground, Android or the user can terminate your process at any time. As I noted in my answer, it is unlikely that the user will keep your application in the foreground permanently.

Comment: Ok, you're right now I get it. Thanks for help, I'll use AlarmManager then.