# How to write a cron expression or Set a timer that will be executed only once in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, cron, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

I am sending *push notifications* to android apps everyday morning from backend `Spring-MVC` java application. For this I have created a **cron job** and initialized a bean in **WebConfig**(`@EnableScheduling`). This bean will send notifications everyday morning.

But if the user don't read it, then only I must send another notification in the evening at particular time. Otherwise I shouldn't send anything. How to write a *Cron expressen* or *Scheduler* or *Set a timer* to send only **once** at a **particular time**, **only on that day**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to [@Jordi Castilla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3850595/jordi-castilla) answer, I found this code helpful to run particular task for desired time only once.
Scheduling a task is to specify the time when the task should execute. 
For example, the following code schedules a task for execution at `11:01 P.M.`

```
//Get the Date corresponding to 11:01:00 pm today.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
Date time = calendar.getTime();

timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), time);
```

**Source:** 
[scheduling a task is to specify the time](http://bioportal.weizmann.ac.il/course/prog2/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html)

Answer (score 2):

That makes no much sense to launch a `cron` process only for once...

Pattern `0 0 hour-minute * * ?` will program task for an hour and minute, but **each day**:

```
0 0 15-45 * * ?    // will execute task at 15:45
```

But to achieve this, look at [this answer that shows how to use a Timer to create a thread that runs when needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11361356/3850595):

```
private static class MyTimeTask extends TimerTask
{    
    public void run()
    {
        //write your code here
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //the Date and time at which you want to execute
    DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = dateFormatter .parse("2012-07-06 13:05:45");

    //Now create the time and schedule it
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new MyTimeTask(), date);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I must use TimerTask. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you once again,

Comment: I got the code for getting current date. But Time is fixed(hardcoded). How to use it in code? For Eg: Date date = dateFormatter .parse(currentDate, "13:05:45"); ? Sorry for asking this bad question but please help me.

Comment: parse the class attribute or user input and put in a variable, after just use it like in the example....

Comment: Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();  __ 
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); __
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); __ 
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); __ 
@Jordi Castilla 
Date d1 = c.getTime(); __ 
DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); __
Date date = dateFormatter.parse(d1.toString() + "13:05:45"); __ 
Am I correct?

Comment: I am getting unparsable date exception for my above code. Please help me.

Comment: I think you miss a blankspace between date and time, Try this: `Date date = dateFormatter.parse(d1.toString() + " 13:05:45");`

Comment: I tried your solution. But I am getting " java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Jun 15 17:49:46 IST 2015 17:52:00"

Comment: `d1.toString()` is not returning `yyyy-MM-dd`, you must parse it with         `SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");` and `Date date = dateFormatter.parse(formatter.parse(d1) + " 13:05:45");`

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful answers and solving my problem. :+1