# How to fire a method at a specific time with Java?

Tags: java, time

I'd like my program to call a method when it is 9 pm.

So, is there a listener that checks continuously time and fires a method at a certain time?

And if not, how can I make the program call a method every 60 seconds?

Thanks a lot <3

Comment: Have you read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: This has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361332/how-to-call-a-method-on-specific-time-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no listener that checks periodically in Java unless you make one yourself. To schedule something to occur at a particular time you typically delay execution by the difference in time between now and the desired time. You can do this quite nicely with Java 8's date/time API. If you want something to trigger at 9pm today, I suggest:

```
final LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
final LocalDateTime ninePMToday = LocalDateTime.now()
                                               .withHour(21)
                                               .withMinute(0)
                                               .withSecond(0)
                                               .withNano(0);
final ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
ses.schedule(() -> System.out.println("It's 9pm!"),
             now.until(ninePMToday, ChronoUnit.MILLIS),
             TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

You can also schedule it to repeatedly execute at 9pm every day with a small tweak to the scheduler call:

```
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> System.out.println("It's 9pm!"),
                        now.until(ninePMToday, ChronoUnit.MILLIS),
                        TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Change the code above to adjust for your 60 second interval (check the documentation for the scheduler methods for more information).

Comment: Or more simply: `LocalTime.now().until(LocalTime.of(21, 0), MILLIS)`;

Comment: Yup indeed, thanks @assylias!

Comment: **Incorrect.** You should be using `ZonedDateTime` rather than `LocalDateTime`. The `Local…` types have no concept of time zone and so cannot account for anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use any scheduler. I would suggest to use QuartzJob. You will need:

```
class MyJob implements Job {

    public void execute (JobExecutionContext ctx) {
    }
}
```

CronTrigger:

```
CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger();
trigger.setName("myTrigger");
trigger.setCronExpression("0 * * * * ?");
```

and a new scheduler:

```
Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
scheduler.start();
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Comment: Don't know why you're being downvoted. Using an scheduler like Quartz is a perfectly valid option, especially if OP wants to have more than one job and different schedule types. No need to reinvent the wheel. (However it's true that your example is not valid for the original "every day at 9 PM" schedule requested).