# run a function on a specific date and hour

Tags: java, android, datetime, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a smart irrigation system on raspberry pi.I want to start the pump from Android Studio on a specific date and hour.I have the code to start the pump but I do not know how to run the code on a specific date and hour.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you running "plain" Java on the RPi, or running the Android Operating System on the RPi?

Comment: Hello Eugenmihai, If you need to run code on android at certain conditions, your best bet is to use WorkManager [how to schedule work with it](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/), otherwise, check [how to do it with AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms). Short of this, you're going to have to provide a little bit more context on what you're trying to do, it's quite vague.

Comment: I have a RPi web server and I send a GET request from my android app to activate the GPIO(pump). I just want an example of how to call a function on a specified date.

Comment: What did your search bring up? I expect that you can find a good answer much faster that way than by waiting for someone to type a new one here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361332/how-to-call-a-method-on-specific-time-in-java

Comment: Great. Does this answer your question? [How to call a method on specific time in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361332/how-to-call-a-method-on-specific-time-in-java)

Comment: Yes,it helped me in some way.Thanks for the help.