# What's the best way to schedule a function that contains start date and end date?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I need a method that has the ability to start on specific dates and times, and that can also finish on specific days and times.

for example, on 06/20 at 07:00am a function must be started that collects some data from the device and uploads it to an API, and I want it to end on 06/20 at 10:00am.

Comment: Functions generally end when they're done.

Comment: but I need that for a period of time, be running a post to an API every 5 min for example...

Comment: can you use Spring boot and the solution which i have provided ? will that work for you ?

Comment: hello!  no, i need to do all this inside my android project.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `RxJava(RxKotin)`. It will allow you to make a throttleable `observable` that runs on the `IO thread`, that you can `subscribe` too.
It could be throttled to 5 mins per `emit`. When the `observable` emits your `subscriber` should do the `api post`.
As for when to start the `observable` you could use this [How to call a method on specific time in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361332/how-to-call-a-method-on-specific-time-in-java) . You can setup two of them one at 7am that `subscribe`s to the `observable` and one at 10am that `unsubscribe`s from the `observable`.

Answer (score 0):

Incase your application is a SpringBoot, you can explore the **@Schedule** annotation. you can create your cron and specify the sec/min/hour/day/days in the cron and make it run as per your schedule :

Below are the steps to enable Spring Schedules

1. Add **@EnableScheduling** annotation to your main class.
2. Add
   **@Scheduled** annotation on top of the method which you want to run in intervals or at specfic schedule. There are multiple ways in
   which you can create your schedule you can read the documentation
3. For your case you can create a cron e.g.   **@Scheduled(cron = "0 0
   07-10 20 JUN ? ")**

Above cron will run on 20 June from 7am to 10am.
You can also add a last optional parameter in the cron where in you can specify the year incase you want it to run only for a particular year.

in the cron below are the values :

**second/minute/hour/day/month/dayofWeek/year**

**The year parameter is optional**

Incase you need more information about the values which you can use in cron please read the official documentation :

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm
Adding another link for @Scheduled annotation :
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks